# Dynamically records not getting to cursor in trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, cursors

I am using cursor in trigger in MySQL. I want to get records of recently added `id`. I am using this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `calculate_property_ratings` AFTER INSERT ON `node` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE property_id integer;
DECLARE ratings integer;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT field_rating_rating, field_property_detail_target_id from field_data_field_rating as fr JOIN field_data_field_property_review as pr on pr.field_property_review_target_id = fr.entity_id JOIN field_data_field_property_detail as pd on pd.entity_id = pr.entity_id WHERE pr.field_property_review_target_id = NEW.nid;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END;
call dolog(concat('node id-->', NEW.nid));
IF(NEW.type = 'review') THEN
    call dolog(concat('type-->', NEW.type));
    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO ratings, property_id;
            call dolog(concat('ratings -->', ratings));
            call dolog(concat('property_id -->', property_id));
            IF NOT(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM average_rating_property WHERE (pid = property_id))) THEN
              INSERT INTO average_rating_property (pid,total_ratings,total_count) VALUES (property_id, ratings, 1);
            ELSE
              UPDATE average_rating_property SET total_ratings = total_ratings + ratings AND total_count = total_count + 1  WHERE pid = property_id;
                call dolog('at update');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END IF;
END
```

If I provide static value instead of `NEW.nid` at line no.4 then I am getting records and  loop is working, else loop is not working. It means `NEW.nid` is not working in cursor. But it is working while logging at line no. 7.

Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `CURSOR` in a Trigger.

Do use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead of your select+insert/update.

IODKU can handle multiple rows at once, but I don't see why that would happen.  Perhaps Cursor's `SELECT` belongs there?

A typical pattern is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (...)
    SELECT ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        a = VALUES(a), ...
```